# How to get value from oracle stored in || separated?

Tags: oracle11g

I am new in oracle and I want to get the value from a column which is stored as  "**Ashu||123 ||Main Menu|ENG||1|1**".
as you can see each value is separated by || symbol.in the above value Ashu is the customer name and 123 is the id, I want both value as customer-name and customer id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the query below, I include some test data "on the fly" (not part of the solution; use your actual table name instead of `test_data` in the main query, and your actual column name instead of `str`). I included several special cases for testing, to make sure the query works correctly in all cases. I assume the first value (before the first `||`) is the customer name and the second the customer id, and the rest of the input string can be ignored. I looked in particular to see that the query handles `null` values correctly (assuming they may happen in your data).

I left the customer id as a string; if it must be a number, it may be better to wrap it all within `to_number()`.

```
with
     test_data ( str ) as (
       select 'Ashu||123||Main Menu|ENG||1|1' from dual union all
       select 'Misha||125'                    from dual union all
       select 'Babu||||Main Menu|NZL||?'      from dual union all
       select 'Rim||'                         from dual union all
       select 'Todd'                          from dual union all
       select '||139||Other Stuff'            from dual
     )
-- end of test data (only for testing and illustration) - not part of solution
-- SQL query begins BELOW THIS LINE
select str,
       regexp_substr(str, '([^|]*)(\|\||$)', 1, 1, null, 1) as cust_name,
       regexp_substr(str, '([^|]*)(\|\||$)', 1, 2, null, 1) as cust_id
from test_data
;

  STR                            CUST_NAME  CUST_ID
  -----------------------------  ---------  -------
  Ashu||123||Main Menu|ENG||1|1  Ashu       123
  Misha||125                     Misha      125
  Babu||||Main Menu|NZL||?       Babu
  Rim||                          Rim
  Todd                           Todd
  ||139||Other Stuff                        139

  6 rows selected.
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but  it looks bit diffcult. i resolved it by   select  NVL(SUBSTR(uui, 0, INSTR(uui, '||')-1), uui) AS CustomerName,REGEXP_SUBSTR(uui, '[^||]+', 1, 2) AS CustomerID

Comment: @ashishjayara - If you know for sure that the customer name and the customer id can **never** be `null` (not now, not in the future, two years from now when the query will still be used), then the solution can be simplified. Is that the case? The solution "looks bit difficult" because it must handle that possibility. Also, you may benefit if you ask about the parts of the answer you didn't understand.

Comment: yes i got it now Thanks :-) i was confused with your test data but i have understood now,,thanks again